# How to get rid of a java.lang.NullPointerException when output is acceptable?

Tags: java, for-loop, nullpointerexception

This is a bit complicated for me to explain so please bear with me. I am simulating a process identifier (PID) manager that allocate PIDs. It's been expanded to consist of a multithreaded program that will allocate PIDs, sleep for a random period of time, and then release the PIDs. I have three classes; a PID class, a Thread class, and a driver. I have an array of PIDs and and an array of Threads in the driver. I've managed to assign PIDs to every Thread object in the array but I always get a java.lang.NullPointerException at the end. This is the code:

```
    public class PID {

    private int pid;                    // Unique process identifier
    private boolean availability;       // Used to determine PID's availability--1 for available, 0 for unavailable

    public PID() {};                    // Empty constructor for PID object

    public PID(int p, boolean a) {      // Constructor for PID object with parameters
        pid = p;
        availability = a;
    };

    public void setPID(int pid) {                           // Sets PID's value
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public void setAvailability(boolean availability) {     // Sets availability of PID
        this.availability = availability;
    }

    public int getPID() {                   // Gets array of PIDs
        return this.pid;
    }

    public boolean getAvailability() {
        return this.availability;
    }

    public void allocatePID(int pid) {      // Will allocate a PID and return PID
        this.setPID(pid);   
        this.setAvailability(false);
    }

    public void releasePID() {              // Will release PID to be available for use
        this.setAvailability(true);
    }
}
```

The Thread class

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyThread extends PID implements Runnable {

    public MyThread() {};   // Constructor for thread object                            

    public void run() {

    Random gen = new Random();                      // Generates random values
    int sleepTime;                                  // Sleep time
    sleepTime = gen.nextInt(60000 - 1000) + 1000;   // Generates random sleep time between 1 and 60 seconds (1000 ms and 60000 ms)

    try {   
        System.out.println("This thread will sleep for " + sleepTime + " seconds.");
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 
        System.out.println("The thread has been terminated");
    }

}
```

and the driver

```
 public class PID_Driver {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Random gen = new Random();          // Will generate a random numbers
        int randomInt;                      // Random integer values
        boolean randomBool;                 // Random boolean values

        final int NUM_OF_PIDS = 100;            // Constant number of PIDs
        final int NUM_OF_THREADS = 20;          // Constant number of threads

        int j = 0;

        PID[] pids = new PID[NUM_OF_PIDS ];         // Array of PID objects
        MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[NUM_OF_PIDS]; // Array of threads

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PIDS ; i++) {                        
            pids[i] = new PID();                            // Creates a new PID object
            randomInt = gen.nextInt(5000 - 300) + 300;      // Generates a random integer value between 300 and 5000
            pids[i].setPID(randomInt);                      // Sets each PID value with random integer
            randomBool = gen.nextBoolean();                 // Generates a random boolean value
            pids[i].setAvailability(randomBool);            // Sets each availability status with a boolean value
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PIDS; i++) {
            System.out.printf("\n%-10s   ", "PID value ");
            System.out.printf("%8d", pids[i].getPID());
            System.out.printf("%8s", pids[i].getAvailability());
        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++)
            threads[i] = new MyThread();                        // Creates new thread

        while (threads[NUM_OF_PIDS-1] == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PIDS; i++) {
                    if ((pids[i].getAvailability())) {
                        threads[j].allocatePID(pids[i].getPID());
                        System.out.println("This thread has a PID value of " + threads[j].getPID() + " and its availability is now " + threads[j].getAvailability());
                        ++j;
                }
            }

        }
         // for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            //threads[i].run();                             // Run the thread
//          threads[i].releasePID();                        // Release the thread

//      }

    }
    }
```

I'm aware that it has to do with how I've written my for loop to assign PIDs to the threads based on availability. I've even tried adding a while loop condition in an (insane) attempt to stop the loop once every thread has been assigned a PID but I've been unsuccessful.

EDIT: This is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PID_Driver.main(PID_Driver.java:52)
```

So basically the NPE is appearing at this line:

```
threads[j].allocatePID(pids[i].getPID());
```

Comment: Can we get a stack trace?

Comment: @DavidChristo If I may ask, why would a stack trace be needed in this case?

Comment: When exceptions happen, it is far easier to track down the causes when you know exactly where the program was when it died.

Comment: one place which _can_ be the reason of NPE is that `NUM_OF_PIDS > NUM_OF_THREADS` and you get tail of `threads[]` set to `null`, since you initialize only first `NUM_OF_THREADS` elements, which triggers NPE at `threads[j].allocatePID(...)`

Comment: @DavidChristo: Ah, okay. I was unfamiliar with what stack traces were but I see what you're saying. I'll include it right now.

Comment: your code seems like a variation of `producer-consumer`, it's natural to employ some subtype of `BlockingQueue` here, along with some kind of `Executor`.

Comment: @VictorSorokin: Yes, that's where the NPE is pointing to but I still don't understand why. What do you mean by tail of the `threads[]` set to null?

Comment: @user1729250 it means that you create `threads[]` with `NUM_PIDS` elements set to `null` by default, and then initialize first `NUM_THREADS` elements with new instances of `MyThread`. Since `NUM_PIDS > NUM_THREADS`, last 80 elements of `threads[]` still set to `null`, that gives NPE, when you try to access them later on.

Comment: @VictorSorokin But how can the last 80 elements of `threads[]` be set to null when only 20 of them were created? EDIT: OH I made a silly mistake! Thank you for noticing that.

Comment: @user1729250 in Java language, array elements set to `null` upon creation, and stay this way unless explicitly set to anything else. And, then, what else can they be set to? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your code, you create an array of 100 threads:

```
MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[NUM_OF_PIDS]; // Array of threads
```

However, you only initialize the first 20:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++)
    threads[i] = new MyThread();                        // Creates new thread
```

Then, later on, you call this method:

```
threads[j].allocatePID(pids[i].getPID());
```

Unless you are doing something else with j that I cannot see that keeps it within 0 <= j < 20, the moment j=20, it will try to call that method on an uninitialized object, resulting in the exception.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Victor is right, it's always going to throw a NPE when `j` gets to 20. If you want to go to `threads[NUM_OF_PIDS-1]` in your while loop, then you'll have to populate `threads[20]` through `threads[99]` with new `MyThread` objects.

Otherwise, if you just want to make sure all threads get a PID, then change your while loop condition to:

```
while (threads[NUM_OF_THREADS-1].getPID() == 0) {
    ...
}
```

I'm guessing this is a copy-pasta error. This line

```
MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[NUM_OF_PIDS]; // Array of threads
```

Should be

```
MyThread[] threads = new MyThread[NUM_OF_THREADS]; // Array of threads
```